# Create read only customer attribute in Magento 1.9.x

Tags: php, magento, hash, magento-1.9

I'm trying to create a custom (and readonly) attribute for any registered user, also for new users, which take the ID of that user and make it an hash with a key to use it later to validate the user in other system.

For example:

```
<?php
    echo hash_hmac('ripemd160', '21', 'the-secret-key');
?>
```

The idea is every time one user is registered the hash number are added to the database as an attribute, and later when the user data is consulted (using this hash number) can the user info retrieved.

Thanks